Can you say "I was admitted to the company last week"?
I know we can say "be admitted to a hospital/club/society", but what about "company"? I mean to say that I was hired by the company, but I wonder if "admitted" or some other word might also fit this context.

I was admitted to the company last week.


No. Hiring is not characterized in English as an admitting.

There are other words that may be appropriate. Employed by the company and contracted to work for/with the company are examples that come to mind. Which word is best will depend greatly on the precise nature of the relationship.

We are admitted to institutions, broadly construed. Hall of Fame, hospital, fraternity, Guiness Book of World Records, the Royal Academy, etc.

The process of being shown to your desk, introduced to coworkers, and given basic training in company culture and rules is often called onboarding.  It can last an hour, a morning, or a week or two, depending on the nature of the job and the organization.   "I was onboarded this morning at my new job." or "Last week I began the onboarding process at my new job."

Thanks a lot everybody.
